# Retrieve one user's information from the backend with an AngularFire & Firebase Query

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a Firebase URL - http://whatever.firebaseio.com/ and I'd like to store users keyed off by their username:

```
users
|
-- username1
   |
   --username: 'username1',
   --realname: 'John Doe',
   --age: 30
--username2
   |
   --username: 'username2',
   --realname: 'Jane Doe',
   --age: 29
```

I insert the data from an AngularJS service - something along the lines of:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL + '/users');
var users = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

users[username] = {
  username: username,
  realname: realname,
  age: age,
  $priority: authUser.uid
};

users.$save(username).then(function() {
  console.log("user saved");
});
```

(authUser.uid would be in my case something like 'simplelogin:12' as I'm using the Simple Login strategy)

This works fine. However, what I struggle with is to retrieve one user's information from the backend:

```
var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid)).$asObject();
query.$loaded().then(function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.$id); // returns 'users'? why?
  console.log(snap.$value); //returns null
  // I would like to retrurn an object that contains the user information, for example:
  // Object {username: 'username1', realname: 'John Doe', age: 30}
});
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Right, so I have modified my data structure and query - **only** for testing purposes

```
users[authUser.uid] = { // note I am keying off from the uid now
  username: username,
  realname: realname,
  age: age,
  $priority: authUser.uid
};

// and this works like a charm (notice limit(1)
var query = $firebase(ref.limit(1)).$asObject();
query.$loaded().then(function() {
  console.log(query[authUser.uid]);
});
```

However, this still doesn't work:

```
var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid)).$asObject();
query.$loaded().then(function() {
  console.log(query[authUser.uid]); //returns undefined
});
```

**2nd update**

This does not set the priority:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL + '/users');
var users = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

    users[username] = {
      username: username,
      realname: realname,
      age: age,
      $priority: authUser.uid
    };

    users.$save(username).then(function() {
      console.log("user saved");
    });
```

This however sets the priority correctly:

```
    ref.child(username).setWithPriority({
              username: username,
              realname: realname,
              age: age,
   }, authUser.uid, function() {
       console.log(users);
   });
```

**Update 3**

This now works:

```
var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

    var User = {
        create: function(authUser, username) {
            users.$add({
                username: username,
                age: age
                $priority: authUser.uid
            }).then(function() {
                console.log(users);
            });
```

However this adds a FB generated id as the key. How can add my key? `users[username].$add(...)` errored out.

**Update 4**

Based on the comments and the code samples from the other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690209/209103), this is what I've come up with:

Attempt 1:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASEURL + '/users');
var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
users.push({username: username, age: age, $priority: authUser.uid});
            users.$save(username).then(function(){
                console.log('saved');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error); //returns: Invalid record; could determine its key: joe 
            });
```

Attempt 2 - added the FixedKeysFactory to project

```
users[username] = {
  username: username,
  age: age,
  $priority: authUser.uid
};
users.$save(username).then(function() {
  console.log("saved?!"); 
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error); //returns: Invalid record; could determine its key: joe
);
```

Both error out with the Invalid record message :(

**Update 5**

Because I wanted to key off from the username, I had to modify Kato's original code:

app.factory('FixedKeysFactory',
    function($FirebaseArray, $firebaseUtils) {
      return $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
        $add: function(data) {
            this._assertNotDestroyed('$add');
            if (angular.isObject(data) && typeof data.username === 'string' ) { //note data.username
                return this.$inst().$set(data.username, $firebaseUtils.toJSON(data)); //note data.username
            }
            else {
                return this.$inst().$push($firebaseUtils.toJSON(data));
            }
        }
    });
});

This was quite a ride .... Thanks for all your help

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/24267098/209103: "The first parameter passed into startAt is a priority, not a record key". Are you indeed passing in a priority?

Comment: Second: a Firebase query returns a collection, even if it's a collection of only one item. So I'd expect to see `$asArray()` where you now have `$asObject()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I set the $priority when I call $save - does that look correct to you? I set $priority to be 'authUser.uid' which I then use as well to retrieve the data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I guess the question is, can priority be something like 'simplelogin:11'

Comment: "A priority can be either a number or a string" (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/setpriority.html)

Comment: I think I know what is wrong but I don't know why. Please see the 2nd update

Comment: @Tamas see [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674894/setting-priority-in-angularfire-0-8?noredirect=1#comment40128494_25674894) to answer your note about priorities.

Comment: Thanks @Kato - unfortunately I still don't get it after reading the other SO question. Does it mean that I can only set the $priority for 'users' but not for any other element?

Comment: @Kato - okay I think I eventually got it: See my updated - and hopefully my last question :)

Comment: Kato's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25690209/209103) describes how to extend the array factory to provide your own `$add` method for that purpose.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that causes additional errors - namely 'ReferenceError: FixedKeysFactory is not defined' but I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I'm adding yet another update :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularfire - Firebase query / sync first x items in document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259562/angularfire-firebase-query-sync-first-x-items-in-document)

Comment: I'm going to copy the yield of this conversation into an answer, but in the future I encourage you to post new questions to Stack Overflow when the focus shifts. This prevents questions and answers from getting too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

When you store your user records, set a [priority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data)

```
var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

var User = {
    create: function(authUser, username) {
        users.$add({
            username: username,
            age: age,
            uid: authUser.uid,
            $priority: username
        }).then(function() {
            console.log(users);
        });
```

Then you can use [`startAt`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html) and [`endAt`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/endat.html) to recall a specific user record based on that priority:

```
var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(username).endAt(username)).$asObject();
query.$loaded().then(function() {
  console.log(query[username]);
});

//Note: This is pretty much the same code from your original question
```

Alternatively, you may want to consider using the `uid` as your priority. It's a much safer way to match newly logged in users with their existing records:

```
var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
var User = {
    create: function(authUser, username) {
        users.$add({
            username: username,
            age: age,
            uid: authUser.uid,
            $priority: authUser.uid
        }).then(function() {
            console.log(users);
        });
```

You can recall them with the request from your original question:

```
var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid)).$asObject();
query.$loaded().then(function() {
  console.log(query[username]);
});
```